# Aspose Markup fields too wide

Tags: linq, ms-word, aspose

I'm using the reporting engine for aspose and everything is working fine.

The issue I have is that my document model has some larger names in it. I didn't build the model and I would rather not create a new one just for reporting, but if that's my only option I will. Thought I'd check here first.

Example:

<<[NatureOfInjury]>><<[NatureOfInjuryOptionA]>>
Hurt   Hit thumb with hammer

The markup for <<[NatureOfInjury]>> is wider on the word document than the value that will end up going in there, and it's making formatting the document difficult.

Is there any way other than changing the object model to make the markup smaller, independent of the actual text values that will go in there?

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no other way to populate template tag with data source field name using LINQ Reporting. You need to use the same name in template document and data source.

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.